# Random Facebook iOS SDK auth token invalidated by API

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I randomly get the following message when trying to access the graph from my iPhone using Facebook iOS SDK:

> response string: {"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"Error validating access token: The session was invalidated explicitly using an API call."}}

I'm not sure why this is because I call the graph immediately after I login, so the token should be valid.  Also, this happens randomly around 30% of the time.  Does anyone know how to go about debugging this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been experiencing the same issue.  It happens with any graph request after calling authorize immediately after a successful logout callback (with the idea being that a different user can log in from there).

The authorization screen will say that the user's already accepted the permissions (even though they're supposed to be logged out now...) and if they hit ok it will cause the issue.  Almost as if the auth process reissues an invalidated token because it doesn't get the memo that they've logged out.  However it won't happen if the user hits the "not you?" link and logs in as someone else as intended (or if they log in again as the same user), so this isn't a major issue in my case.

As for an answer / fix, I made mine fix itself by detecting the error response from the graph call and then making another call to authorize.  Not ideal though, since it annoys the user with two consecutive app switches...

Comment: yah.i did the same thing..hope they fb fixes it.

Comment: Such strange behavior. Having the same issue with FB JS-SDK and omniauth. If I deauth an app, then try to sign back in, I get the issue. If I deauth, sign out, sign back in use the app, I don't. So facebook ties something to your logged in "session" which is being cached when calling FB.Login and getting the response.