# iphone+FaceBook acess token expired error

Tags: iphone

i am using two url to get the information of nearby areas by passing current lat-long.
The two urls are :-

1) https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=Hospital&center=72.000,23.000&distance=100000?access_token=

2) https://graph.facebook.com/151116474914629

Now it is showing me the proper result .But then it is showing me the below error:-

**{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1325840400. The current unix time is 1325842498.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}**

How to get over this..
Please help me

Comment: see this link, it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878812/random-fb-ios-sdk-auth-token-invalidated-by-api